# LinPhone lib Android не видит входящий звонок

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sip

LinphoneCore 5.0.65-1-gc84aaa355

разбираюсь в легаси коде сип приложения и столкнулся с такой проблемой

если сначала зарегистрироваться на сип сервере то входящие вызовы приходят нормально

но если входящий вызов уже идет и я в это время регистрируюсь на сип сервере, то линфон в упор не видит этот вызов

попробовал как оно на десктопной версии, там все норм, приложение закрыто, отправляю звонок  с сервера, запускаю приложение и звонок сразу идет

подскажите знающие люди куда копать